# How can I stop HTTP from escaping quotes?

Tags: c#, php, html, json, http

I'm using C# to POST some data to a webserver running PHP.

I'm sending a JSON formatted object to the server in the POST data.

The data looks something like this when it leaves the C# program:

```
json_text={"abc":"hello", "dfg":"world"}
```

I have the server printing the data exactly as it received it using **echo $_POST['json_text'];** The script outputs the following:

```
{\"abc\":\"hello\", \"dfg\":\"world\"}
```

I'm not very familiar with how POST data is packaged into an HTTP packet. I opened up WireShark to look at how quotes are sent in POST data and it looks like they are replaced with **%22**. However, I tried replacing my quotes with %22 and it did NOT stop the quotes from being escaped when it is outputted.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off PHP's [magic_quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) option. That's probably where the backslashes are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your `json_text` object as follows, not quoting the property names and using single quotes instead:

`json_text = { abc : 'hello', dfg : 'world' }`

Comment: At first I thought you were setting up an Javascript object and sending it via an Ajax call.  If this data is being sent in C#, why don't you just create an anonymous object and use the built-in JSON helpers: `return Json(new { abc: "hello", dfg: "world"});`