# Java sends a JSON string in POST request with escaped double quotes

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop HTTP from escaping quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715650/how-can-i-stop-http-from-escaping-quotes)

I am creating a JSONObject and sending JSON string to a server in a POST request body.

```java
public String toJson() {
    JSONObject filter = new JSONObject();
    try {
        filter.put("gender", gender.getCode());
        filter.put("feature_id", productCategory);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject filterObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        filterObject.put("filter", filter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filterObject.toString();
}
```

So I'm creating a request:

```
private IJsonExecutorInterface requestExecutorForRelativePathAndParams(String path, WebParams params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(rootUrl + path);

    if(params != null) {
        postRequest.setHeader("content-type", params.getContentType());
        postRequest.setEntity(params.getFormEntity());
    }

    // Blah blah

    return executor;
}

public IJsonExecutorInterface getProducts(ProductFilter filter, int offset, int limit) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    WebParams webParams = new WebParams();
    webParams.addPair("filter", filter.toJson());
    webParams.addPair("offset", String.format("%d", offset));
    webParams.addPair("limit", String.format("%d", limit));
    return requestExecutorForRelativePathAndParams("products", webParams);
}

// WebParams class


public class WebParams {
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
    private String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    public WebParams() {
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void addPair(String name, String value) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public HttpEntity getFormEntity() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
    }
}
```

I see it in debugger: it's ok.

But on my server I getting something like this:

```
Array
(
    [filter] => {\"gender\":\"w\",\"feature_id\":\"41_7459\"}
    [offset] => 0
    [limit] => 18
)
```

The quotes ARE escaped.

I don't want to replace something on the server. `replace("\\\"", "\"")` in Java doesn't affect on the string.

Comment: Answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715650/how-can-i-stop-http-from-escaping-quotes. It's not a Java problem. It's a PHP problem.

Comment: I have the same problem now using Retrofit lib, have you found a solution to this or did you have to handle it on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your using a UrlEncodedFormEntity, which, according to the docs is 'An entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs' ([http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html]). I've never used this, but it doesn't sound like its what you want, as you are sending data in the post body, not through URL parameters.

I've used the `StringEntity` class before to send json data via post, although it only encodes a string, not name/value pairs, so you've got to do a bit more work to put the string in a format you want to deal with on your server:

```
public class WebParams {
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
    private String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    public WebParams() {
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void addPair(String name, String value) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public HttpEntity getFormEntity() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //TODO: Build a string in what ever format you want. 
        //      This will include the gender & feature_id fields as well as the json
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for(NameValuePair nvp : params) {
           builder.append(nvp.getName()).append('=').append(nvp.getValue()).append(',');
        }

        //Now that we have a string to send to the server, get your entity!
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(b.toString());
        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I have to send other params in POST request as well as JSON and all of them should be with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. So I have to replace escaped quotes on the server...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem to use simple quotes instead of double quotes? Because I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: I must use double quotes. JSON field names are placed in quotes.

Comment: Yes, but (at least when you parse it on JavaScript), simple quotes are as valid as double quotes. Try it out.